# How to change text alignment in QTabWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4, pyside, qtabwidget

I cannot find a way to set the text alignment in a QTabWidget.

After I've created an instance of this widget, I've set its *tabPosition* property to West, but I wish it showed text/label horizontally.
I've given a look to the Qt's [stylesheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html), but as you can see, the *text-align* property can only be set on QPushButton and QProgressBar.

I already searched on the web, but I just found a [bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-1286), a [non-answered question](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33245-QTabWidget-West-and-horizontal-text), and finally [a user](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25905-QTabWidget-West?p=123636#post123636) that suggests to re-implement the paint() method. 
Maybe I'd solve, but I'm using Python (PyQt or PySide) and I don't know how to do it.

Can you help me?

EDIT: 
thanks to Teukamm, I wrote a bit of code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class HorizontalTabWidget(QtGui.QTabBar):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        for index in range(self.count()):
            painter = QtGui.QPainter()
            painter.begin(self)
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.blue);
            painter.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 10));
            tabRect = self.tabRect(index)
            painter.drawText(tabRect, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.TextDontClip, self.tabText(index));
            painter.end()

     def sizeHint(self):
         return QtCore.QSize(60, 130)

import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()
tabs.setTabBar(HorizontalTabWidget())
widget1 =  QtGui.QWidget()
widget2 =  QtGui.QWidget()
tabs.addTab(widget1, "Widget1")
tabs.addTab(widget2, "Widget2")
tabs.setTabPosition(2)
tabs.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And finally I've my text aligned as I expected, but I've a little (big?) problem: when you click on the right side of every tab button, it doesn't send the [*currentChanged* SIGNAL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html#currentIndex-prop). I've also tried to expand the width of every tabRect, in paintEvent, but it doesn't work. What should I change?

Thank you :)

BTW: you could not inherit from QTabWidget, but from QTabBar ;)

EDIT:

Solved! Just changed the method **sizeHint** in **tabSizeHint** and it works well :)

Comment: you cant override the paint method in puQt?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to override that method, but I thought it was not included in the Python implementation (don't know exactly why I supposed this...)
Thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, you need to create a custom class that is a subclass of QtGui/QTabWidget and redefine the painting method:

```
class HorizontalTabWidget(QtGui.QTabWidget):
   def paintEvent(self, event):
      QPainter p;
      p.begin(this);
      # your drawing code goes here
      p.end();
```

Here's the [documentation for QWidget.paintEvent](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#paintEvent) method that you are reimplementing.

Of course you need to know how painting works in general, please refer to the documentation for [QPainter](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qpainter.html).

Unfortunately I don't have a PyQt installation handy at the moment, so I can't give you a more specific solution.

Comment: I forgot you may need to reimplement sizeHint() as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
However, I've edited the question. Maybe you can help me :)

Answer (score 8):

I've put a worked example together on GitHub that solves this here: https://gist.github.com/LegoStormtroopr/5075267

The code is copied across as well:

Minimal example.py:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from FingerTabs import FingerTabWidget

import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()
tabs.setTabBar(FingerTabWidget(width=100,height=25))
digits = ['Thumb','Pointer','Rude','Ring','Pinky']
for i,d in enumerate(digits):
    widget =  QtGui.QLabel("Area #%s <br> %s Finger"% (i,d))
    tabs.addTab(widget, d)
tabs.setTabPosition(QtGui.QTabWidget.West)
tabs.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

FingerTabs.py:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class FingerTabWidget(QtGui.QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tabSize = QtCore.QSize(kwargs.pop('width'), kwargs.pop('height'))
        super(FingerTabWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QStylePainter(self)
        option = QtGui.QStyleOptionTab()

        for index in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(option, index)
            tabRect = self.tabRect(index)
            tabRect.moveLeft(10)
            painter.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, option)
            painter.drawText(tabRect, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter |\
                             QtCore.Qt.TextDontClip, \
                             self.tabText(index));

    def tabSizeHint(self,index):
        return self.tabSize
```

Comment: Need's a lot of improvement, i have added a lot of things, but for initial script is very good and It works. This is more complete answer, not only for the alignment, but for 'Finger Tabs' too. Thanks!