# Python PyQt4 Qpainter active message

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qpainter

I was trying to display my `QTabWidget` text horizontally with the `Tabposition` set to 2 (left side). After searching around, i found the following code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607709/how-to-change-text-alignment-in-qtabwidget).

```
class FingerTabWidget(QtGui.QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tabSize = QtCore.QSize(kwargs.pop('width'), kwargs.pop('height'))
        super(FingerTabWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QStylePainter(self)
        option = QtGui.QStyleOptionTab()

        painter.begin(self)
        for index in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(option, index)
            tabRect = self.tabRect(index)
            tabRect.moveLeft(10)
            painter.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, option)
            painter.drawText(tabRect, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.TextDontClip, self.tabText(index));
        painter.end()
    def tabSizeHint(self,index):
        return self.tabSize
```

I managed to apply this code by just simply using this

```
Tab = QtGui.QTabWidget()
Tab.setTabBar(FingerTabWidget(width=260,height=28))
```

Everything looks exactly like i expected and working fine but i am keep getting this error message everytime i mouse over on one of the tab.

```
QPainter::begin: Painter already active
```

Even though it does not affect the functionality of my program, i would like to know what is causing this error message. A simple explanation will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calls to `painter.begin()` and `painter.end()` are redundant, as these are both done automatically when the painter is created and deleted. Re-calling `painter.begin()` on an active painter is technically an error, which is why you are seeing those warnings.

If you simply remove the redundant lines, the error messages should go away.

PS:

An alternate way to fix the issue would be to omit passing `self` to the constructor of the painter. This would leave the painter uninitialized, so the call to `painter.begin(self)` would then be necessary to make it active.

So, in summary, you should do either:

```
    painter = QtGui.QStylePainter()
    painter.begin(self)
    ...
```

or just:

```
    painter = QtGui.QStylePainter(self)
    ...
```