# Vertical alignment of tab-headers in PySide.QtGui.QTabWidget

Tags: python, layout, pyside, qtabwidget

The default arrangement of tab-headers in PySide.QtGui.QTabWidget using the code

```
tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()
tabs.addTab(QtGui.QLabel('some label on Tab1'), 'Tab1')
tabs.addTab(QtGui.QLabel('some label on Tab2'), 'Tab2')
```

is horizontal. Is there a way of placing the headers vertically, i.e. below each other?

QtGui.QVBoxLayout used as

```
layout =  QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
tabs.setLayout(layout)
```

seems to apply only to the area within a tab.

Are QListWidget and QStackedWidget the alternatives to be used in this case?

Comment: Yep - I came to realize that after a good night's sleep (cf. my answer-post below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. I found another question to satisfy my requirements: [How to change text alignment in QTabWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607709/how-to-change-text-alignment-in-qtabwidget)