# How to resize horizontal qtabwidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtabwidget

I'm following the instruction of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607298/pyqt-qtabwidget-horizontal-tab-and-horizontal-text-in-qtdesigner) but I have a problem with the size of the tabwidgets. I would like to adjust it to the size of the text.

[image]

I have add an exemple of code where the size of the tab doesn't match with the size of the labels :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = TabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 30, 581, 481))
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Case 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Case 2"))

from tabwidget import TabWidget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the tabwidget.py which is provided in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607298/pyqt-qtabwidget-horizontal-tab-and-horizontal-text-in-qtdesigner)

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

class HorizontalTabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        option = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()
        for index in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(option, index)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, option)
            painter.drawText(self.tabRect(index),
                             QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.TextDontClip,
                             self.tabText(index))

    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        size = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        if size.width() < size.height():
            size.transpose()
        return size

class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setTabBar(HorizontalTabBar())
```

Comment: Hi, I have added an exemple

Comment: Publish the `tabwidget.py` module.

Comment: Ok, I've add it @S.Nick

Comment: Please post the image that you get after running the example that you published. I get a completely different look.

Comment: @S.Nick please find the image of the exemple [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zl_MM2USOP8Jek0W4MPQjyEH28XCJtbp/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: strange, but it displays correctly on my computer

Comment: @S.Nick your are on linux I suppose ?

Comment: No, I have Windows

Comment: [`Qt.TextDontClip`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TextFlag-enum): "If it's impossible to stay within the given bounds, it prints outside.".

Comment: I think it might be because of the retina screen