# PySide create horizontal tabs with horizontal text

Tags: python, pyside, qtabwidget

I am trying to use this solution by @eyllanesc:

[pyqt qtabwidget horizontal tab and horizontal text in QtDesigner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607298/pyqt-qtabwidget-horizontal-tab-and-horizontal-text-in-qtdesigner/46616419?noredirect=1#comment103968609_46616419).

My main window has a QStackedWidget in which one of the pages is the page with horizontal tabs. I used Qt designer to create a dialog with a tab widget, and set the tabPosition to West. Then I promoted the TabWidget like shown in the original post.

[image: Qt Designer]

This is what the resulting window looks like. There are no outlines around the tabs, and the tabs are not clickable:

[image: Resulting window]

This is my main code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from tabs import TabsUi_Dialog

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.mainMenuWidget = MainStack(self)   
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainMenuWidget)

        self.show()


class MainStack(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainStack,self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.stack = QStackedWidget(parent=self)
        self.tabPage = TabPage()
        #Add Pages to Stack
        self.stack.addWidget(self.tabPage)
        #Add Stack to Layout    
        self.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.tabPage)
        layout.addWidget(self.stack)

class TabPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(TabPage,self).__init__(parent)
        self.tabs = TabsUi_Dialog()
        self.tabs.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit( ret )
```

And this is the tabs.py file created after converting the Qt Designer UI file with py-uic:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class TabsUi_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tabWidget = TabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtGui.QTabWidget.West)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Tab 1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Tab 2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

from tabwidget import TabWidget
```

Comment: provide a [mre], try with: `app.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: @eyllanesc added. Also app.setStyle("fusion") doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Shock-o-lot Try calling `QApplication.setStyle('fusion')` before creating `app`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I tried that, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @eyllanesc The tabs are clickable to change tabs, but there is no visual feedback on the tabs themselves. If I setStyle('Windows''), then the tabs look a lot better, however the tab above the one selected gets highlighted rather than the one selected. I don't, however, want to use Windows theme in my application.