# The stylesheet is not applied to custom QTabWidget in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

I use [this custom tabwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607298/pyqt-qtabwidget-horizontal-tab-and-horizontal-text-in-qtdesigner), and now I want to change the background color of my tabs but the stylesheet did not do any thing.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class HorizontalTabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def paintEvent(self, event):

        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        option = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()
        for index in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(option, index)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, option)
            painter.drawText(self.tabRect(index),
                             QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.TextDontClip,
                             self.tabText(index))

    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        size = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        if size.width() < size.height():
            size.transpose()
        return size


class RTabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setTabBar(HorizontalTabBar())
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QTabBar::tab {
                background-color: rgb(18, 18, 18);
            }
            
            QTabBar::tab:selected {
                background-color: rgb(81, 81, 81);
            }
            
            QTabWidget::pane {
                border: 1px solid #121212;
                background-color: rgb(81, 81, 81);
            }
        """)
```

the code above is my custom widget that i promote to my old tabwidget.

change the tab background color.

Comment: Does it work if you create the tab just by code? If it doesn't, what OS are you using? What is the output of `QApplication.style().objectName()`? Are you setting other stylesheets in the application or any parent widget? If it *does* work as standalone, and the problem only occurs when using Designer, how are you using it, with a `pyuic` generated file, or with the `loadUi` module? Are you sure you're not setting a stylesheet on the QTabWidget in Designer? Note that Qt style sheets (QSS) are only *based* on CSS (and using the 2.1 version as a reference); that `transform` property is useless.

Comment: I already create the tab just by code. It works when I did not use my custom widget. I think there is something wrong with my selectors but I can not handle it!

Comment: Sorry but you probably misunderstood my question: with "create the tab just by code" I mean using your `RTabWidget` directly from code and *not* by using designer (pyuic or uic) with your widget promotion. Note that if in Designer you set another stylesheet for the QTabWidget, this will completely override the one you set in the `__init__` (calling `setStyleSheet()` on the same widget is not cumulative, it always reset any QSS previously set with that call).

Comment: I understand, No I am not using designer. and I call `setStyleSheet()` for my object in my main window but still not changing the style. I Solve the problem by using proxystyle. thank you for trying to helping me.

Comment: If you want to use stylesheets, using a proxy style will have lots of limitations. You say that you don't use designer, but in your question you talk about "promotion". In the context of Qt, that is only achieved through Designer files. If you meant something else, then "promotion" is the wrong (and misleading) term, and if you actually are *not* using Designer files, then please provide a full, comprehensive [mre]: only based on the code you provided, it should work as expected, meaning that you're doing something different somewhere else, and we cannot know that if you don't show it to us.