# QTabwidget's tab text alignment not working

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtabwidget

i am trying to show the opened tab text in left .i wrote that in stylesheet.but it is not working.

here is the stylesheet i used

```
QTabWidget QTabBar{
    background-color: #373738;
    height: 30px;
}

QTabWidget QTabBar::tab{
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #136ba2;
    border-style: 1px rgb(67, 67, 67);
    height: 30px;
    width: 130px;
    color: #136ba2;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

QTabWidget QTabBar::tab:selected{
    background-color: #5A5B5C;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
}
QTabWidget QTabBar::tab:!selected{
    background-color:#353536;
    color:  #B4B4B4;
}
QTabWidget QTabBar::tab:hover{
    background-color:  #5A5B5C;
    color:  #ffffff;
}
```

[here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUuRD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the tab button widget to show the tab text.

Have a label, with left aligned text:

```
QLabel * button = new QLabel("text");
button->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
```

Set the tab text to empty string if necessary:

```
ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->setTabText(index, "");
```

Set the label as the tab button widget:

```
ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->setTabButton(index, QTabBar::LeftSide, button);
```

You can still style the label,  adding a QLabel entry in the tab widget stylesheet:

```
QLabel{ color: white; }
```

Only problem here: no way to style the label text depending on selection (i.e. making the selected tab text bold) using CSS. But still feasible catching the tab widget `currentChanged` signal:

```
void Form::on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int index)
{
    for(int i=0; i<ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->count(); i++)
    {
        QWidget * button = ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->tabButton(i, QTabBar::LeftSide);
        if(button != nullptr)
        {
            QFont font = button->font();
            font.setBold(i == index);
            button->setFont(font);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible with stylesheet, according to the doc :

> **text-align**  [...] This property is currently supported only by QPushButton and QProgressBar.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties

Comment: any other way to achieve this??

Comment: Others have asked without any answer from what I looked, it seems that there is nothing straightforward other than handling yourself the painting of the text. You can check the answers to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/3607709/6165833

Answer (score 0):

One workaround(not clean method) I found is add some extra space at the end of the title;

```
QString tabTitle = "Page 1     ";
```

Will move the text towards left.